# Does pigeonhole principle apply for all groups (and monoids)?

Tags: group-theory, elementary-set-theory, pigeonhole-principle

I'm reading *Rosen*'s book and it has a proof to show that a finite subgroup (set) is closed under a composition law.

It says for some $i$ and $j$, $i < j$, $a^i = a^j$ i.e, $a^i = a^i \circ a^{j-1}$. I really don't get it.

How is this equal? Is the pigeonhole principle applicable to all groups?

Comment: Use ^ for superscript.  For instance a^{j-1} produces $a^{j-1}$

Comment: Hello, welcome to Maths.SE. I've edited your question using MathJax, our maths renderer. Check the source (by clicking [edit]) to see how it works. For further information about writing maths at this site see e.g. [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/), [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/70559/155238), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help#latexhelp/notation).

Comment: your question is about why ai=aj using the pigeon hole principle?

Comment: I understand that $a^i$ = $a^j$ because of pigeonhole principle where at least two of them will be the same in the set but how is it that $a^i = a^i ∘ a^{j-1}$ ?

Comment: Thanks @Lord_Farin , I'm returning back to University after more than 7 years of programming. Hope Maths.SE will be a great community to be with in this journey. Cheers !

Comment: @SebastianSantana Glad to have you aboard :).

Answer (score 2):

The pigeon hole principle says that for $n$ things grouped into $m$ distinct sets, at least one set will contain $\lceil n/m \rceil$ elements. Here, the elements are the distinct integer powers that we're raising $a$ to, and they're put in different sets according to what element of the group the $a^i$ corresponds to.

So, if there are more powers than elements of the group, eventually more than one power will be associated with the same element. So, $a^i = a^j = a^i a^{j-i}$. You have a $-1$ there, and that's erroneous.

**Edit to add:** Notice that this doesn't work for infinite groups, because you will never have more powers than elements of the group.

For example, in the group $(\Bbb Z, +)$, we will never have $n^i = n^j$ for $i \ne j$, because in this group the notation $n^i$ stands for $n \cdot i \in \Bbb Z$.

Comment: I understand $a^i$ = $a^j$ but how is it $a^i=a^ia^{j−i}$ ?

Comment: Well, we're using that $a^i = a^j$, then we're taking the j and rearranging it into $i + (j - i)$, and then using that to break the product up. For instance, if i = 3 and j = 7 we have $$a ^3 = a^7 = a*a*a*a*a*a*a = aaa * aaaa = a^3 * a^{7-3}.$$

Comment: But what is the point of doing that? isn't $a^i = a^j$ enough? I'm really very sorry for my silly questions. I apologize.

Comment: And also, this holds only when the the composition law is multiplication.

Comment: The point of doing that is probably that you then have a cancellation rule, $a*b = a*c \iff b=c$, which you can then apply simply and arrive at the fact that every element of a finite group has a finite order. But I don't have the text, so I don't know.